# If $V \subseteq W$ and dim$(V)$=dim$(W)$, then $V=W$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

If $V,W$ are subspaces of $\mathbb{R^n}$.

My proof simply states that if the dimension, $m$, of both subspaces are the same, then we know that $m$ linearly independent vectors in both $V$ and $W$ span $V$ and $W$. Thus, if $V \subseteq W$, these $m$ linearly independent vectors must be the same, and so the span of both subspaces must be the same $\Rightarrow$ $V = W$.

Is this the type of rigor expected in such a proof? I can see conceptually why the claim is true, but I'm not really sure how to organize my thoughts in such a way that "proves" the claim.

Answer (score 1):

You have some of the right ideas for a proof, but your wording is kind of confused and jumbled. A good proof should follow clearly from "known" facts/theorems.

Your idea about spanning is a good one. Start there.

Take a basis, $\beta$, for $V$. This consists of $m = \dim(V)$ linearly independent vectors which span $V$. Then since $V \subseteq W$, you have that the vectors in $\beta$ belong to $W$. So $\beta$ is a collection of $n$ linearly independent vectors in $W$. Thus (since $\dim(W)=m$) this collection is a basis and thus spans $W$. Now you have

$$V = \mathrm{span}(\beta) = W$$

done. :)

Answer (score 0):

Extend a basis $v_1,\dotsc,v_m$ of $V$ to a basis $v_1,\dotsc,v_{m+n}$ of $W$. Then 
$$
m=\dim V=\dim W=m+n
$$
so $n=0$. It follows that $v_1,\dotsc,v_m$ is also a basis for $W$. Hence $V=W$.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is correct. However, to make things completely clear you can put it in this way. If $W$ is a proper subspace of $V$, then we can choose a basis for $W$ and extend it to a basis of $V$ by adding vectors to it. But this is impossible since $\dim V=\dim W$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\dim(V)=m$. Implicitly, this means that there exists a basis of $V$ whose cardinality is $m$-sized. Let us label these vectors as $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_m$. By definition, we know that these vectors must be linearly independent. Next, consider some $w \in W$. In order to show that $V=W$, we need only show that $W \subseteq V$.

Consider some arbitrary $w\in W$. There are two cases to address: $w\in V$ or $w \in W \setminus V$. If $w \in V$, then we are done. So, suppose that $w \in W \setminus V$.

> **Relevant lemma**: If $v_1, v_2, \cdots , v_{m}$ are linearly independent and $v_{m+1}$ is not a linear combination of $v_1, v_2, \cdots , v_{m}$, then $v_1, v_2, . . . , v_m,v_{m+1}$ are linearly independent independent.

---

The proof of this lemma is brief: If $v_1, v_2, \cdots , v_{m}$ are linearly independent, then we know the only coefficients that satisfy $\alpha_1v_1+\cdots+\alpha_mv_m=0$ are $\alpha_1=\cdots=\alpha_m=0$. Next, consider the expression: $\beta_1 v_1 +\cdots +\beta_m v_m+\beta_{m+1}v_{m+1}=0$. We know that an expression like this *always* has a solution (the trivial solution where all coefficients equal $0$)...but we need to determine if this is the *only* solution. Suppose $\beta_{m+1}\neq 0$. Then we can rewrite this expression as:

$$\frac{\beta_1 v_1 +\cdots +\beta_m v_m}{-\beta_{m+1}}=v_{m+1}$$

But this would mean that $v_{m+1}$ is a linear combination of the $m$ vectors. So we must have that $\beta_{m+1}=0$. So our expression $\beta_1 v_1 +\cdots +\beta_m v_m+\beta_{m+1}v_{m+1}=0$ reduces to the expression: $\beta_1 v_1 +\cdots +\beta_m v_m=0$, for which we already know that the only coefficients which satisfy this are when $\beta_1=\cdots=\beta_{m}=0$. Noting that $\beta_{m+1}=0$, too, we have our conclusion.

---

Returning to our proof, we know that $w \notin V$. Our vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_m$, by properties of a basis, span $V$. Therefore, we can equivalently state that $w \notin \text{span}(\{v_1,\cdots,v_m\})$...but this just means that $w$ is *not a linear combination* of vectors $v_1,\cdots,v_m$. We can thus apply our lemma, which lets us conclude that $v_1,\cdots,v_m, w$ are linearly independent vectors. Because $V \subseteq W$ and $w \in W$, this means that we have $m+1$ linearly independent vectors in $W$. However, that would mean that $\dim (W) \geq m+1$, which contradicts our original assumptions that $m=\dim(V)=\dim(W)$. So, clearly, there is no such vector $w$ that is $\in W \setminus V$...restated, $W \setminus V = \emptyset$, implying that $V=W$.